# Ajax Post call response is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, webforms, controller

```
 var generateOrder = {
      "orderitems": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Raddish",
          "rate": 30,
          "weight": "3",
          "amountperweight": 90
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "Peas",
          "rate": 35,
          "weight": "4",
          "amountperweight": 140
        }
      ],
      "totalamount": "230",
      "discount": "10",
      "netamount": "220"
    }
```

Why ajax post call is hitting to controller with null value.

```
var generateOrder = {
                    orderitems: newRecords,
                    totalamount: $("#totalamount").val(),
                    discount: $("#TextBoxdiscount").val(),
                    netamount: $("#TextBoxnetamount").val()
                }

                   $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/Orders/GenerateOrder",
                    data: JSON.stringify(generateOrder),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("response", response);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                    }
                });


         public class OrderCart
                {
                    public int id { get; set; }
                    public string name { get; set; }
                    public int rate { get; set; }
                    public string weight { get; set; }
                    public int amountperweight { get; set; }
                }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GenerateOrder")]
        [ActionName("GenerateOrder")]
        public List<OrderCart> GenerateOrder(List<OrderCart> generateOrder)
        {
          return generateOrder;
        }
```

[Controller null response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGDQN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're posting an object that has both header and line items, but your Post method is expecting just a list of line items. That mismatch between the structure of the json object you're sending and what the POST is expecting could be part of your problem.

Comment: so how i should pass object?

Comment: Try passing just the "orderitems" array, without the total and net fields, and see if that works. If so, that will indicate that a mismatch of the objects is probably what's happening. 

If that's the case, you'll need to create an Order class that has an array of OrderItems in it, along with the total and net etc fields, and then put that as your POST param, i.e. public Order GenerateOrder(Order generateOrder)

Basically, you want the objects to match in structure so .NET can match your json to the .NET object.

Comment: Great! Please mark mine as the answer then, if you don't mind, so it will show as solved :)